# Delimiter tens and units in c++ literals

Tags: c++, delimiter, literals

In Java I can do:

```
int i = 1_200_200;
```

How can I do something the same in c++? I mean what should I use instead of an underscore?

Comment: BTW: You should pick a language, becasue as I answered and AFAIK in [tag:c] it's not possible, but it appears that in c++ it's possible.

Comment: "*tens*"......?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since C++14 you can use single quotes (') for [integer literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) to improve the readability, e.g.

```
int i = 1'200'200;
```

> Optional single quotes(') may be inserted between the digits as a
>   separator. They are ignored by the compiler.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Huh? For the same reason it's used in natural language of course, i.e. readability. For binary constants it would be very useful I think, i.e. `0xde'ad'f0'0d` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can use the ordinary quote. For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int x = 1'234'567;

    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In C such a feature is absent.