# Integer literal with single quotes?

Tags: c++, integer, literals

What exactly as been assigned to value? I am surprised that this has compiled at all.

```
//g++  7.4.0

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto value = 123'456'7;
    std::cout << value << std::endl;

    value += 1;
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

outputs:

```
1234567
1234568
```

Comment: you can use ' to separate thousands

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3781.pdf the feature was added in cpp 14

Comment: @Raildex: convention of separation depend on country, C++ doesn't enforce any convention, so you can still "misplace" the quote (as in OP's example).

Comment: [Delimiter tens and units in c++ literals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46254084/995714), [Is there a way to write a large number in C++ source code with spaces to make it more readable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50559636/995714), [Making large constants in C source more readable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10977260/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Representing big numbers in source code for readability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220217/representing-big-numbers-in-source-code-for-readability)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since C++14,

from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

> Optional single quotes(') may be inserted between the digits as a separator. They are ignored by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

C++ allows single quotes to separate the digits for better reading:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

> Optional single quotes(') may be inserted between the digits as a separator. They are ignored by the compiler.